# Handling push notification effectively

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, push-notification

I have a query regarding push notification.

Whenever a push comes and user is working on some XYZ controller and push requires another controller to be initialized and shown. Now should I show the push controller on top of the current active controller and take the user back to the currently working controller, once done?

What if the push controller has some actions involved and is a complete set of functionality associated with it. Should we restrict actions when a push comes.

What is the best deal?

Answer (score 0):

It depends heavily on the flow and organization of your application.   In a tab bar based application, you should have a tab for handling the notification activity, and place a badgeValue for the corresponding UITabBarItem.   You could also show an alert offering the possibility of switching to the "handle notification" area on the other tab.    Tab Bars are a good way of having "simultaneous" access to differing flows and switching back and forth between them without having to manage saving and restoring the VC flow yourself.

Comment: Mine is a custom view based app where I have combination of modal and custom views.